# Android WiFi ADB plugin not working. Giving error

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed the Android WiFi ADB plugin to run the app wirelessly. But it's not working it's giving error that Phone and PC should be connected on the same network. I use my phone hotspot to run the internet on my PC. Then I use another phone but then also same error. Someone says it will not work because you use the mobile hotspot for an internet connection on your PC. But when I try to connect another phone then also the same issue. But the same way my friend also does. he also uses the internet using a mobile hotspot but it's working fine on his phone. I have a POCO F1 Phone.

Comment: You can use either a phone's hotspot and can send the app to this phone itself or can use another phone for sending apk. Both works. But how you do it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this hoping this may help others as well as I find it helpful for my use.

1. First, Turn on ADB in your phone's developer options. You can search `Your_phone_model developer options` to find that.
2. Second, After turning on ADB, Connect your phone with data cable to your laptop/desktop.
3. Open a Command prompt window, Type `adb tcpip 5555`, Press allow in adb prompt shown in your phone, it will show restarting adb in tcpip mode. Now, disconnect the USB cable. You can use different port number to connect another device.
4. Type `adb connect your_phone_ip:5555` as for example `adb connect 192.168.43.1:5555` in case of hotspot. You can check Phone's IP in WIFI's advanced setting of your phone or in status section.
5. Now, Everytime your device restarts, repeat steps 3-4.

You can also make a script, just type `adb connect your_phone_ip:5555` in a notepad file, save it as `name.bat` file, right click on it and send to desktop (create shortcut), in the settings on the shortcut, set any shortcut keys. Now, anytime you want to connect, just press the shortcut keys. That's how I do it. You can further open Android studio by this script so it will open Android Studio as well.

Remember, whenever it says `Device is Offline`, restarts your phone's wifi and reconnect it.